# Nested views | Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, nested

I need to neste a view that's already nested...

i mean, i have the view `app` inside this i have 5 nested views, but i need inside one of these 5 views, anoter nested view

its something like

```
--> App
----> view 1
----> view 2
----> view 3
----> view 4
----> view 5
------> view 5.1
------> view 5.2
------> view 5.3
------> view 5.4
```

> Controller

```
// includes
$data['footer'] = $this->load->view('includes/footer', NULL, TRUE);

// App
$data['menuProfile'] = $this->load->view('app/menuProfile', NULL, TRUE);
$data['sidebarMenu'] = $this->load->view('app/sidebarMenu', NULL, TRUE);
$data['topNavigation'] = $this->load->view('app/topNavigation', NULL, TRUE);
$data['menuFooter'] = $this->load->view('app/menuFooter', NULL, TRUE);

// Dashboard
$data['dashboard'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dashboard', $data, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['dinp'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dinp', NULL, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['dispTitle'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dispTitle', NULL, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['percent'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/percent', NULL, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['temp'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/temp', NULL, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['velocity'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/velocity', NULL, TRUE);


$this->load->view('includes/head');
    $this->load->view('app', $data);
$this->load->view('includes/jquery');
```

i tried this way but i got this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: percent

Filename: dashboard/dashboard.php

Line Number: 10

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\m2m\application\views\app\dashboard\dashboard.php Line: 10 Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\m2m\application\controllers\app.php Line: 34 Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\m2m\index.php Line: 315 Function: require_once
```

what im doing wrong? (*noob at codeigniter*)

***Edit***

> App | View

```
<body class="nav-md">
  <div class="container body">
    <div class="main_container">
      <div class="col-md-3 left_col menu_fixed">
        <div class="left_col scroll-view">
          <div class="navbar nav_title" style={{border: '0'}}>
            <a href="index.html" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>M2MWare!</span></a>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <?=$menuProfile?>
          <br />
          <?=$sidebarMenu?>
          <?=$menuFooter?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?=$topNavigation?>
      <!-- PageContent -->
      <?=$dashboard?>
      <?=$footer?>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

> Dashboard | View

```
<div class="right_col" role="main" id="Dashboard">
      <div class="">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_content">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 widget widget_tally_box">
                  <!-- percent -->
                  <?=$porcentaje?>
                  <!-- dinp -->
                  <?=$dinp?>
                  <!-- dinp -->
                  <?=$dinp?>
                  <!-- temp -->
                  <?=$temp?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here's an img how display the error in the browser

[image]

i need write something, because SO... just ignore this part

Comment: can please change the name of percent variable

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39760680/edit) your answer and include the view file `app`'s code.

Comment: @DFriend Done... Mayank i did it, but wont work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dashboard.php` contains the code you show under

> Blockquote

and it is loaded with this line

```
$data['dashboard'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dashboard', $data, TRUE);
```

then the problem is that you do not pass your secondary views to `dashboard.php`.

I believe all you need to do is reorder one line of code and pass the appropriate data to the "dashboard" view. Try this.

```
// Dashboard
$dataDashboard['dinp'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dinp', NULL, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['dispTitle'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dispTitle', NULL, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['percent'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/percent', NULL, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['temp'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/temp', NULL, TRUE);
$dataDashboard['velocity'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/velocity', NULL, TRUE);
$data['dashboard'] = $this->load->view('app/dashboard/dashboard', $dataDashboard, TRUE);
```

Comment: Oh i see, its the order, because if i declare the dashboard at the beginning doesn't work, but at the end it works. Thanks you!